# net beans xdebug waiting for connection error?

Tags: php, netbeans

i have done almost every thing to resolve this issue. . .but message waiting for connection is still there. . . . . is there any way to debug this issue. i am using xampp server. OS windows

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Users\arslan\Desktop\xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-        vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=off 
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req 
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

i tried on ecllipse too with both zend and xdebug. connection problem continue to exists.
i have already gone through stackoverflow and netbean forums.
i have alredy wasted my full day to figure out the solution but fialed.

Comment: 1. Have you verified that XDebug extension is enabled (these spaces looks suspicious)? 2. Have you allowed netbeans on windows firewall (even if it is localhost)?

Comment: Just use 'UWamp' package. when you install it you have configured and ready to use xdebug and zend debuger. after i moved to this package i didnt wanted to return to XAMPP(very slow and buggy).
about your problem check if in "phpinfo" its showing that xdebug is active and the path is correct.

Comment: thanks. . .ur replies helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked.
 Actually i was not restarting apache after changing php.ini.

working php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension= "C:\Users\arslan\Desktop\xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" 
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

OS windows

Xampp

php 5.4

NetBeans 7.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The Library file really exists?

Change the port 9001 to 9000, restart apache and try again.